# Why postgres "scan index(btree)" phase of plan returns all rows?

Tags: postgresql, b-tree

I have some misunderstanding with btree using Postgres 9.6.

I'm using `SELECT max(total_amount) FROM bookings`;

Total rows count 2111110, total_amount - numeric(10,2)

I have index on this column

```
CREATE INDEX ON bookings USING btree (total_amount);
```

When I'm using explain I see:

[image]

And as I know Btree is ordered tree, so to find min key value you should go left from root to end, maximum - right

So why postgres gets all rows but not one from scan index node?

Comment: Please do not post execution plans as (barely readable) screen shots. Add them as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: If you add analyze option to the explain the actual number of rows fetched will be shown in each node of the plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't get all the rows - if you look closely there is a `Limit` step right above the Index Only Scan Backwards - and that estimates only 1 row. So the index scan stops after the first row that was retrieved from the index.

Comment: postgres is not performing a read from the heap, the index has sufficient information to satisfy this query. in other words, postgresql isn't fetching a `row` at all. the terminology is a bit confusing as the execution plan refers to index entries as rows as well.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: that's what I meant with "*stops after the first row that was retrieved from the index*"

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is an execution plan, and the numbers are estimates, not true counts.  A quirk of the way execution plans are reported is that the estimated number of rows for the node assumes the node will run to completion.  Note that the LIMIT node above it then scales back both the row estimate and the cost estimate to account for the fact that it is expected to stop early.  It would be possible to push that scale back reporting from the LIMIT node down to the lower node, but that is just not the accounting convention that has been used.

If you do the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` of the plan, it would also report actual counts, and you would see that the actual count is 1.  It is a bit confusing that the estimated counts and the actual counts are not reported on the same basis here.